Is modifying form validators based on backend response secure in an enterprise-level cloud full-stack project?
I am working on an enterprise-level Cloud Full-Stack project, where I’m part of a team managing multiple table views. Each table has its own add/edit form, and certain form fields may be read-only based on user access permissions.
Currently, we handle this by sending a request to the backend, which responds with access control information. Based on this response, we modify the validators for each form control (e.g., marking fields as read-only or requiring them).
Is this approach secure? Specifically, is it safe to rely on client-side form validators being updated based on the backend response, or is there a more secure way to handle access control and form validation?
The tech stack for this project is:

Spring Boot (Backend)
Angular (Frontend)
PostgreSQL (Database)


If client-side validation is the only validation you have in place, then no, it's absolutely not secure, regardless of how you determine what the client-side validation rules should be.
You need to implement server-side validation, and should only rely on client-side validation to improve the user experience.

What would you say is the recommended way to to do server-side validation?
